# #Pragma pack giving warning when compiling

Tags: c, sockets, struct, pragma, pack

I'm creating the following structures in C and only the Packet structure will be sent over a UDP socket. I want to pack the structure to avoid different alignments on different computers (Not sure if I need to pack both or only the one I'm sending). When I compile this, I get the following warning for both:

```
warning: ignoring #pragma ( [-Wunknown-pragmas] #pragma(pack);`
```

Why is it that my pragmas are being ignored? And how can this be fixed.

```
#pragma push(pack, 1);
struct packet{ // the actual packet within the node
    uint32_t seqnum;
    uint32_t checkSum;
    uint32_t numPackets; // number of packets to send
    char data[1024]; // the data in the packet
};
struct packetNode{ //for the linked list
    struct packet p;
    struct packetNode *next;
};
#pragma pop(pack)
```

gcc version:

```
gcc --version 
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
```

Comment: Maybe because your compiler doesn't support the `#pragma`.

Comment: Not directly to do with the question, but if you're concerned about interoperability between different computers, have you considered different endian-ness between sender and receiver?

Comment: yes, I do htonl() to the data felids before sending and upon receiving I do ntohl()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `push` and `pack` syntax is backwards compared to what the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas) says it supports.  The semicolon after `#pragma` is superfluous.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct packet{ // the actual packet within the node
    uint32_t seqnum;
    uint32_t checkSum;
    uint32_t numPackets; // number of packets to send
    char data[1024]; // the data in the packet
};
struct packetNode{ //for the linked list
    struct packet p;
    struct packetNode *next;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Although the link is to the GCC 5.2.0 documentation, it is the same if you change the 5.2.0 in the URL to 4.8.4.

Incidentally, for the `Packet` data structure shown, the direction to pack the structure is superfluous on any plausible machine architecture. There are plenty of structures where that would not be the case (indeed, the `PacketNode` structure is one such, though I see no benefit to packing it as it is not sent over the wire), but the `Packet` structure will be identical in layout in both packed and unpacked forms.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Unfortunately, I fixed it as shown and I am still getting the same warning :/

Comment: @Rachelle: Curious: the GCC 4.8.4 manual on [structure packing pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas) says it should be OK.  I tested the pasted code in my answer with 5.2.0 and compilation options `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -c pack.c` — where `pack.c` was exactly the code shown — and got no warnings or errors (but the original code failed to compile). Check your line numbers; check you removed the semicolon; check you edited the correct file.